# Java convert GIF image to PNG format

Tags: java, png, gif

I have to build a Java servlet that receives an image and returns that image converted to PNG format. How can I achieve this?
By converting I don't mean changing the file extension, like some examples suggest.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15):

Try this out:

```
package demo;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main( String [] args ) throws IOException { 
        File input = new File("input.gif");
        File output = new File("output.png");

        ImageIO.write( ImageIO.read( input ), "png", ouput);
    }
}
```

Read [ImageIO](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html).

Of course, you may want to read and write from an stream instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
ImageIO.write(ImageIO.read(new File("img.gif")), "png", new File("img.png"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use ImageIo to save an Image in any format your want.