# Convert GIF images to PNG format, 32 bits depth

Tags: java, image, png, converters, gif

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4208054/1225328) is a solution to convert GIF images to PNG format. The problem is that the generated PNG images are in 8 bits depth (in my case at least).

Is there a way to force them to be in 32 bits depth? The best would be using the `javax.imageio.ImageIO` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert the `BufferedImage`, redrawing a copy with the desidered colour model. Not extremely efficient, but practical:

```
      File input = new File("/tmp/input.gif");
      File output = new File("/tmp/output.png");
      BufferedImage im1 = ImageIO.read( input );
      BufferedImage im2 = new BufferedImage(im1.getWidth(), im1.getHeight(), 
                BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
      im2.getGraphics().drawImage(im1, 0, 0, null);
      ImageIO.write(im2 , "png", output);
```

Comment: Awesome, many thanks! I don't really care about efficiency for this tool: I just don't want do convert my GIF images manually `;)`

Comment: Bear in mind that, in principle, you lose nothing by saving as 8-bit PNG. A GIF image is always indexed (256 colors palette).

Comment: Yes, but GIF images loose quality when included in a PDF document(at least with the PDF tool I'm using), 8 bits PNG images too, but 32 bits PNG images not.